# Unaccountable pixels, where are they coming from?

Tags: html, css

Given the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box2 {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="box box1" value="input text here" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea class="box box2" rows="1">input text here</textarea>
</div>
```

([code in codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGeNpN))

I'd expect the height of the two `wrapper` elements to be the same, but that's not the case.

The heights of the two `box` elements are the same: `17px`.
The height of the `box1` wrapper is: `28px`.
The height of the `box2` wrapper is: `31px`.

Two questions:

1. Why is the height of the `box1` wrapper is 28 and not 27?
2. Why isn't the height of the two wrappers the same? And how do I make them the same?

Comment: The wrappers are the same height, but the box are *not* both `17px`. A `textarea` with `rows=1` is evidently not the same size as an `input type="text"`.

Comment: @meagar Not for me. When I check the height in the chrome developer tools it shows me the heights I included in my answer.

Comment: Please reset (set to 0) all margins and paddings on your inputs and textareas. Additionally set the height and line-height to a specific value. This is probably causing the issue.

Comment: @JoostS I already set the margins and paddings for both `box` elements to 0. I added `line-height: 15px` but that has no effect. Even if I change it to `20px` the height do change, but both wrappers still have different heights

Comment: Are you checking the size in the snippet or your own code? Like for @meagar, they aren't the same for me in Chrome either. The reason for this (in what I'm seeing anyway) is because they are using different fonts, which have slightly different sizes. If you change the font in the text area to sans serif, they are the same size.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Even with the same font (added `font-family` to the class of `box`) the two wrappers have different heights.

Comment: I was about to ask if you are now at least seeing the same height input & textarea... but you have been all along, haven't you? The other strange thing is your box1 is 13.6px and box2 is 14.4px for me in Chrome, even though they are 17px for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the gap is that `input` and `textarea` are both `inline` (or `inline-block`) element. Though, the gap for `textarea` differs in different browsers.

To fix this, either add `display: block` to `.box` (to both elements) or add `vertical-align: top` to `textarea`.

Comment: That did it! I added `vertical-align: top` and it fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `wrapper`-elements doesn't have the same size is because textarea and input elements are naturally an `inline-block` or `inline` element (depends on the browser). The gap is caused by some browsers because they're reserving space for the content that comes next. Strangely that doesn't apply to `void`-elements like `input`.

To fix this you can apply `vertical-align: top` to the `textarea` or `display: block` to both elements.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box2 {
  resize: none;
}

.fix1 {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.fix2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="box box1" value="input text here" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea class="box box2 fix1" rows="1">input text here</textarea>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="box box1 fix2" value="input text here" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea class="box box2 fix2" rows="1">input text here</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it alright. But I accepted the same answer by @Cons7an7ine as he answered a bit sooner.

Answer (score 0):

`box1` and `box2` aren't the same size and the reason is because they are adapting to the content height, and the default font for both input types is different which results in slightly different heights - even though you have set them both to the same font size, the fonts have slightly different vertical spacing.

Note: You also need to set the line-height on the `wrapper` classes to the same value (I used 1em in the example below).

Check the difference here between your example and when these 2 changes are applied:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box2 {
  resize: none;
}

.testwrapper {line-height:1em;}
.testbox { font-family: 'sans serif';}
```

```html
<p>Your example:</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="box box1" value="input text here" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea class="box box2" rows="1">input text here</textarea>
</div>

<p>With the same font and line-height:</p>
<div class="wrapper testwrapper">
  <input class="box box1 testbox" value="input text here" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper testwrapper">
  <textarea class="box box2 testbox" rows="1">input text here</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't do the trick. Even with the same font the heights of the two wrappers are not the same. The first one is 28 and the second is 30.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I realised I'd forgotten to copy one of the CSS changes into my snippet from my test page - I also set the same line-height for the `wrapper` class. Check the updated snippet and see if its working for you now. FYI, I've put the required changes into separate CSS classes `testwrapper` and `testbox` so you can see exactly what the changes are.

Comment: Still not the same heights. Anyhow, there are 2 answers that got it right. Thanks

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thats very strange... the wrappers in the first 2 boxes are different, but the second 2 with the new CSS are the same - both 18.4px for me. The line-height has the same net result as vertical align in this case, so I'm baffled why you are seeing different results. Glad you found an answer but just for my own curiosity - what are the height you are seeing for the second set of boxes?

Comment: The 3rd one is 27px and the 4th one is 29px